# Finding and replacing values in specific columns in a CSV file using dictionaries

Tags: python, excel

My Goal here is to clean up address data from individual CSV files using dictionaries for each individual column.  Sort of like automating the find and replace feature from excel. The addresses are divided into columns. `Housenumbers`, `streetnames`, `directions` and `streettype` all in their own column. I used the following code to do the whole document.

```
missad = {
'Typo goes here': 'Corrected typo goes here'}

def replace_all(text, dic):
for i, j in missad.items():
    text = text.replace(i, j)
return text

with open('original.csv','r') as csvfile:
text=csvfile.read()
text=replace_all(text,missad)

with open('cleanfile.csv','w') as cleancsv:
cleancsv.write(text)
```

While the code works, I need to have separate dictionaries as some columns need specific typo fixes.For example for the `Housenumbers` column `housenum` , `stdir` for the street direction and so on each with their column specific typos:

```
housenum = {
'One': '1',
'Two': '2
}
stdir = {
'NULL': ''}
```

I have no idea how to proceed, I feel it's something simple or that I would need pandas but am unsure how to continue. Would appreciate any help! Also is there anyway to group the typos together with one corrected typo? I tried the following but got an unhashable type error.

`missad = {
    ['Typo goes here',Typo 2 goes here',Typo 3 goes here']: 'Corrected typo goes here'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is something like this what you are looking for?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=False)   #using pandas to read in the CSV file

#let's say in this dataframe you want to do corrections on the 'column for correction' column

correctiondict= {
                  'one': 1,
                  'two': 2
                 }

df['columnforcorrection']=df['columnforcorrection'].replace(correctiondict)
```

and use this idea for other columns of interest.

Comment: The code works, thank you! but when I repeat the `df['columnforcorrection']=df['columnforcorrection'].replace(correctiondict)` It replaces values outside of that column. For example, I tell it to replace `NULL` values in column `streetname` but it replaces it in `streetdirection` even though I haven't specified that column. @Jessica

Comment: It's actually cleaning up all the NULL values in the csv file regardless of if I have it in the code or if I specify a column. Is that normal?

Comment: it should only impact the column specified, can you do df['columnforcorrection-newcolumn']=df['columnforcorrection'].replace(correctiondict)   , to make a new column with a diff name and see how that is

Comment: Yeah for some reason it was replacing all the NULL values with blanks which is fine but was confused as to why. The code is fine as it is, now I just need to figure out a way to concat/merge these columns without getting a NaN for when the cell is blank. Thank you again!